# Why does loadFactoryPreset affect preGain and wetDryMix properties of AVAudioUnitDistortion?

Tags: ios, swift, distortion, avaudioengine

Why does `loadFactoryPreset(preset: AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset)` affect the `preGain` and `wetDryMix` properties of `AVAudioUnitDistortion`? This implementation seems inconsistent with `loadFactoryPreset(preset: AVAudioUnitReverbPreset)`, which does not alter any properties when changing the preset.

Here's a playground I made to illustrate this point and graphs showing how the properties are altered for each preset.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

let distortion = AVAudioUnitDistortion()
let reverb = AVAudioUnitReverb()

var i = 0

// Distortion

distortion.preGain = 6.0
distortion.wetDryMix = 6.0

while let preset = AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset(rawValue: i) {
    distortion.loadFactoryPreset(AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset(rawValue: i)!)
    distortion.wetDryMix
    distortion.preGain
    i++
}

// Reverb

reverb.wetDryMix = 100.0

i = 0
while let preset = AVAudioUnitReverbPreset(rawValue: i) {
    reverb.loadFactoryPreset(AVAudioUnitReverbPreset(rawValue: i)!)
    reverb.wetDryMix
    i++
}
```

[image]
[image]

All of the distortion presets sound terrible with a 100% `wetDryMix`, so I can't help wondering if this is a bug or if there's a good reason for this behavior.

Comment: You've isolated and documented the behavior so there's no problem; you know what to do (load the preset, then fix the settings you disagree with). What kind of answer would be satisfactory? What's the point of the question? If you don't like it, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I see your point. Sure, I disagree with the implementation, but the question is meant to help me understand the decision for this behavior. Perhaps someone with a background in audio could add some insight. Also, to determine if the behavior could be deemed a bug or not.

Comment: Well, the preset has to have _some_ setting for all the various properties. You're clearly expected to start with the preset and take it from there. I've never seen presets work any other way. They are just starting points. - As for bugs, they are like weeds: if you don't like it, it's a bug.

Comment: In this case, the preset doesn’t need "some setting for all the various properties.” For example, `AVAudioUnitReverb` has a preset for a `SmallRoom` and a preset for `LargeHall`. Switching between these presets changes the effect (e.g. from a small room to a large one). Setting the `wetDryMix` only changes the amount of the effect that is applied–not the effect itself. The same holds true for `wetDryMix` and `preGain` properties in `AVAudioUnitDistortion`. Again, I didn't ask this question simply because I don't like the implementation. Thank you for the feedback though.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you at all. I think you have a legitimate suggestion for Apple and I hope you'll bring the matter to their attention. What I don't see is what you're asking _here_.

Comment: I may report a bug. Still hoping for an explanation if there is one. While testing just now, I did find a possibly valid reason for `loadFactoryPreset(preset: AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset)` to affect the `preGain` property. A positive `preGain` seems to create undesirable feedback when using the `DrumsBufferBeats` preset. This may be isolated to the audio I'm using, though it's possible that the changing properties are meant to account for this sort of thing. `DrumsBufferBeats` is the second circle on the distortion graphs. This doesn't really explain the `wetDryMix` being 100%.